Uniform Fréchet differentiability
Right now, I'm studying concepts of differentiation in Banach spaces, but I'm pretty new. In several references, I've found the following property:
"Let $U\subset X$ be an open convex subset of a Banach space $X$ and $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is uniformly Fréchet differentiable if and only if $f$ is Fréchet differentiable and the map $x\mapsto f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous".
However, none of them proved it. They all say that it's trivial, but I can't figure this out. I've tried to remove the dependence of $x$ from $\delta$ in the $\impliedby$ direction and tried to bound by $\varepsilon$ the quantity $|f'(x)(h)-f'(y)(h)|$ when $\lVert x-y\rVert<\delta$ for the $\implies$ direction, but haven't reached anything.
Could you guys help me? I'd be really thankful!
See you!! :)
Edit: My definition of Fréchet differentiability is
Let $f$ be a real-valued function on an open subset $U$ of a Banach space $X$ and let $S$ be a subset of $U$.
We say that $f$ is uniformly Fréchet differentiable (UF) if it is Fr'echet differentiable at each $x \in S$ and the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}$ is uniform in $x \in S$ and also in $h \in S_X$; more precisely, given any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta := \delta(\varepsilon) > 0$, with the following property: for every $x \in S$, $h \in S_X$, and $0 < |t| < \delta$ with $x + th \in U$, we have
$\left| \frac{1}{t} (f(x + th) - f(x)) - f'(x)h \right| < \varepsilon$.
Definition of Fréchet differentiability

Perhaps that is the definition of "uniformly Fréchet differentiable", not a theorem.

Hi! See the edit, please!

Please don’t use
images for such a crucial part of your question, instead of typing your formulas.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions. This is a PSQ. What were your attempts to prove $\implies$ and/or $\impliedby$?

It's just that I've made no progress so far. I'm trying to eliminate the dependece of $x$ from $\delta$ but I'm not able to.

For which direction  of the iff is this attempt? What did you try for the other one? (better edit your post to include all this, as well as the definition of uniform Fréchet differentiability);

What has this got to do with convex analysis???

Okay, this should solve all the issues. I hope someone can answer my question!

The requirement that the limit be uniform for $h \in S_{X}$ is redundant; a function is Fréchet differentiable if the limit $\underset{t \rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{f(x + t h) - f(x)}{t}$ is uniform for $h \in S_{X}$ (I am unsure why the reference restated this in the definition of uniform Fréchet differentiability).
For your question, see "Differential Calculus in Topological Linear Spaces" by S. Yamamuro. The claim is proved on page 35 (points (1.10.2) and (1.10.3)). The direction ($\Leftarrow$) is rather straightforward, but the other is not. I will not repeat the details here, however.

Also for a reference on the definition of Fréchet differentiability, see "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces (2nd Edition)" by H. H. Bauschke and P. L. Combettes (Definition 2.56) or Functional Analysis and Infinite-Dimensional Geometry by Fabian et al. (Definition 8.1).

Hi! Thank you all for your comments. I've been looking to "Differential Calculus in Topological Linear Spaces" by S. Yamamuro, and saw the proof they give. I think that's a very general proof for a TVS. My situation is simplier, my function goes from an open subset of a Banach space into the real field. Is there a way to simplify the proof?

In 1.10.3 of that book, there is an additional assumption, which you do not mention. @TroubleIsBlack, isn't it necessary for the proof, even in the OP's simpler case where $E$ is Banach and $F=\Bbb R$?

@AnneBauval Thank you for bringing this to my attention; I must have missed it when I looked it over. When I get the chance, I'll go over the details.

@TroubleIsBack Honestly, this goes over my head. I hope you will be able to help.
